# SQL select the first and the last row based on another column (timestamp)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, hql

Hello I am trying to do a select of certain elements on a table.
here is what my table look like
Time,UsrerId,Data.
Now what i want to do is for the same userid i want the first and last Value of data according to the timestamp.

Example:

```
Time UserID Data 
8 PM 1 200 
9 PM 1 300 
10 PM 1 100 
8 PM 2 150 
9 PM 2 250 
10 PM 2 350 
8 PM 3 100
```

So my result should look like:

```
8 PM 1 200 
10 PM 1 100 
8 PM 2 150 
10 PM 2 350 
8 PM 3 100
```

Comment: Example:
Time UserID Data 
8 PM 1 200
9 PM 1 300
10 PM 1 100
8 PM 2 150
9 PM 2 250
10 PM 2 350
8 PM 3 100

So my result should look like:
8 PM 1 200
10 PM 1 100
8 PM 2 150
10 PM 2 350
8 PM 3 100
 Does this make more clear?

Comment: So distinct userid's and when there are multiple records for the same userid sleect the first and the last ones sorted by time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the Min and Max `time` per `userID` then join the result back to the main table to get the other information. Try this.

```
select A.Time, A.UserID, A.Data from yourtable A
join 
(
SELECT   UserID, MIN(Time) AS Min_Time, MAX(Time) AS Max_Time
FROM     yourtable
GROUP BY UserID
) B 
ON a.UserID = B.UserID
and A.time in (B.Min_Time, B.Max_Time) -- (A.time =B.Min_Time or A.time =B.Max_Time)
```

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37ad9/5)**

Comment: Can you look at the comments in the question this is not what i want

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can join the table on itself using the `max` and `min` aggregates:

```
select y.time, y.userid, y.data
from yourtable y
   join (select userid, min(time) mintime, max(time) maxtime
         from yourtable
         group by userid 
   ) t on y.userid = t.userid and y.time in (t.mintime, t.maxtime)
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b263/1)

Comment: Hey i dont think this is correct. What i want is a little different . Please have a look at the modified question which i am doing right now

Comment: @realcoder -- This should answer your current question - how is it not correct?  If you have a different question, perhaps you should post a new one...

Comment: I am checking this. let me go through this query with the extended data that i have and will post the result which i get

Comment: @realcoder Well that doesn't mean this is not correct, just because your question was incomplete. The objective is to get the idea and try to implement it yourself and not look for the exact answer.

Comment: Ok....Sorry about that. I am new to stackoverflow so not aware of the Do's and DOnt's... Thanks Anyway

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   MIN(Time), MAX(Time), UserID, Data
FROM     yourtable
GROUP BY UserID, Data
```

Comment: how will this be the first and last value of data according to the timestamp ?

Comment: Can you look at the comments in the question this is not what i want